# lasso regression and problem with error code : Error in x[Training_data, ] : invalid subscript type 'list'

Tags: r, lasso-regression

When coding I get an error message:

> Error in x[Training_data, ] : invalid subscript type 'list'

This is my code:

```
train <- sample(1:nrow(x), nrow(x) / 2)

test <- (-train)

y.test <- y[test]

lasso.mod <- glmnet(x[Training_data, ], y[Training_data], alpha = 1)
```

What am i doing wrong?
In the beginning of the coding, when coding for x and y, I had problems, and this code was finally accepted by R:

```
y <- Training_data$y

x <- model.matrix(y~. -1, data = Training_data)
```

Is the problem in my coding for the x variable?

The data set is called Training_data.
The response variable is y and 20 features x1, x2, x3 ....x20.

Can anyone please explain this to me?